# Send data from Python backend to Highcharts while escaping quotes for date

Tags: python, jquery, web, highcharts, web.py

I would highly appreciate any help on this. I'm constructing dynamic highcharts at the backend and would like to send the data along with html to the frontend. 
In highcharts, there is a specific field to accept Date such as:
`x:Date.UTC(2018,01,01)`
or `x:2018-01-01`. However, when I send dates from the backend, it is always surrounded by quotes,so it becomes: `x:'Date.UTC(2018,01,01)'`
and `x:'2018-01-01'`, which does not render the chart. Any suggestions on how to escape these quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts expects the values on `datetime` axes to be **timestamps** (number of miliseconds from 01.01.1970). `Date.UTC` is a JS function that returns a timestamp as Number. Values surrounded by apostrophes are **Strings**.

I'd rather suggest to return a timestamp as a String from backend (e.g. `'1514764800000'`) and then convert it to **Number** in JS (you can use `parseInt` function for that.)